# Trouble with including functions in c++

Tags: c++, include, function-pointers, header-files

I am new to c++ and I can't figure out why my headers are not working correctly. If I include the function `fitzhough()` from the main file, everything works perfectly.  However, if I try to add it as a separate file, it gives the error:

```
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\Dan\Documents\C code\RK4\main.cpp|83|undefined reference to `fitzhough(double, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, double, double*)'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

My code is below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**main.cpp**

```
# include < iostream >
# include < fstream >
# include < Eigen/Dense >
# include "gnuplot.h"
# include "addfitzhough.h"

using namespace std;

using namespace Eigen;

Vector2d RK4(Vector2d (*f)(double, Vector2d, double, double*), double t, Vector2d z, double h, double u, double *Iion, int d) {

  VectorXd Y1(d), Y2(d), Y3(d), Y4(d), Y1buf(d), Y2buf(d), Y3buf(d);

  Y1 = z;
  Y1buf = (*f)(t,Y1,u, Iion);
  Y2 = z + 0.5*h*Y1buf;
  Y2buf = (*f)(t+.5*h,Y2,u, Iion);
  Y3 = z + 0.5*h*Y2buf;
  Y3buf = (*f)(t+.5*h,Y3,u, Iion);
  Y4 = z + h*Y3buf;


  Vector2d yn = z + (h/6.0)*(Y1buf + 2.0*Y2buf + 2.0*Y3buf + (*f)(t+h,Y4,u, Iion));

  return yn;
}

int main() {

  //int mydims = 2;

  double u = 0;
  double *Iion;
  double h = .5;

  double y1ans[800];
  double y2ans[800];
  double tans[800];


  Vector2d ycurr;

  Vector2d Ynot, yplus;

  Ynot << .2,
          .1;

  y1ans[0] = Ynot(0);
  y2ans[0] = Ynot(1);
  tans[0] = 0.0;

  for(int i = 1;i<800;i++){
    tans[i] = tans[i-1] + h;
    ycurr << y1ans[i-1],
             y2ans[i-1];
    yplus = RK4(fitzhough,tans[i],ycurr,h,u,Iion,2);
    y1ans[i] = yplus(0);
    y2ans[i] = yplus(1);
  }
}
```

**addfitzhough.h (in separate file)**

```
#ifndef FF
#define FF

using namespace Eigen;

Vector2d fitzhough(double t, Vector2d Y, double u, double * Iion);

#endif // FITZ
```

**fitzhough.cpp**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

Vector2d fitzhough(double t, Vector2d Y, double u, double * Iion) {

  Vector2d dy;

  double v = Y(0);
  double w = Y(1);

  double a = .13;
  double b = .013;
  double c1 = .26;
  double c2 = .1;
  double d = 1.0;

  dy(0) = c1*v*(v-a)*(1-v)-c2*w*v + u;
  dy(1) = b*(v-d*w);

  *Iion = dy(0)-u;

  return dy;
}
```

Comment: What command(s) are you using to compile and link your code?

Comment: I am compiling in CodeBlocks.  I am not using any compiler flags

Comment: @user1968603 You are running a compiler with options. Same thing.

Comment: Bad idea to use whitespace around header names in the `#include <>`

Comment: Sorry, that's not in the actual code, its just left over from me trying to figure out how to format the question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not linking to fitzhough.o (the output of fitzhough.cpp).   Did you insert fitzhough.cpp into the project?

By the way, if you're implementing FitzHugh-Nagumo, his name is spelled FitzHugh :p

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your build system is either not building `fitzhough.cpp` or is not adding `fitzhough.o` in the link stage.

You should add `fitzhough.cpp` to the code blocks project (or equivalent) if you havent.

Comment: Great that fixed it!  What did adding it to the project do differently that it wasn't doing before?

Comment: @user1968603 If you dont add it to the project, Code blocks has no idea that the file exists and that it should compile it. So if it isnt compiled, linker has no idea what `fitzhough` is, hence the error.